# Prove the $\ell^2$ norm of a linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is the maximum eigenvalue

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

If $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation and $\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$, prove that
$$ \lVert A \rVert := \sup \left\{ \frac{\lVert A \vec{x} \rVert_2}{\lVert \vec{x} \rVert_2} : \vec{x} \in \mathbb R^n, \vec{x} \neq 0\right\} = \max \{ \lvert \lambda_i \rvert : i = 1, \ldots, n \} $$
where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalues of a matrix $B$ such that $A(\vec{x}) = B \vec{x}$ for every $\vec{x} \in \mathbb R^n$.

Above is the problem I'm struggling with. I don't know how to show this is true, I searched a lot about it, but didn't understand the concepts! Please help me understand and prove this!

[image: The attached picture is what I have in the paper]

Comment: You may need one extra condition, e.g., "$A$ (or $B$) has $n$ independent eigenvectors". Then you can show the property without difficulty.

Comment: That is all I was given to prove it. It just mentioned that A is an ISOMORPHISM and both domain and range are equipped with the 2-norm.

Comment: Why did you omit an important assumption in the question? Please edit the question to include the hypothesis that A is an isomorphism.

Comment: For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an isomorphism, but $A$ has only one (real) eigenvalue $1$ and (real) eigenvector $(0,0,1)$. In this case $\|A\|\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation $T(1,0)=(1,0), T(0,1)=(1,1)$ is non-singular has only 1 as its eigen value but $||T||=\sqrt 2$. The stated equality holds for symmetric matrices (even singular ones!) but the result claimed is false.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, I have attached the whole question.

Comment: I have given the whole answer :-) I have proved that the result is false.